# Sorting date using KnockoutJS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting, knockout.js

Firstly, I'd like to thank you for reading this post.

I have a small problem, I am trying to sort my posts in descending order of date created. It sorts the date in descending order by the posts created today and yesterday get mixed up.

For example: Posts created show as; 
Created: Today, Created: Yesterday, Created: 29/09/2015, Created: 28/09/2015

After sorting they're displayed in this order:
Created: Yesterday,
Created: Today,
Created: 29/09/2015,
Created: 28/09/2015,

The code I am using is shown below

`foreach.Posts.sort(function (l, r) { return l.Created() > r.Created() ? -1 : 1 })`

Is there a way around this ?

Thank you.

Updated: Added C# Class

```
    [HttpGet]
    public LivePostModel GetPosts(string id, string page = null, string startDate = "", string endDate = "")
    {
        Thread thread = _threadManager.GetThreadByDomain(id);           

        if (thread == null)
            return new LivePostModel();

        DateTime? dtDateFrom = null;
        DateTime? dtDateTo = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate) == false)
            dtDateFrom = DateTime.Parse(startDate);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate) == false)
            dtDateTo = DateTime.Parse(endDate);

        PostWithCount posts = _postManager.GetPosts(new PostsFilter
        {
            SubDomain = id,
            Page = string.IsNullOrEmpty(page) ? 0 : int.Parse(page),
            StartDate = dtDateFrom,
            EndDate = dtDateTo
        });

        IOrderedEnumerable<Post> sortedPosts = posts.Items.OrderByDescending(x => x.Created);
        var postsModel = new List<PostModel>();

        List<string> userKeys = sortedPosts
                .Select(obj => obj.CreatedByUserId)
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

        IList<User> users = _userManager.GetUsersByKeys(userKeys);

        foreach (Post post in sortedPosts)
        {
            User user = users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Key == post.CreatedByUserId);
            if (user != null)
            {
                PostModel postModel = Mapper.Map<Post, PostModel>(post);
                postModel.User = GetUserDetails(postModel.User, user);
                postsModel.Add(postModel);
            }
        }

        var model = new LivePostModel
        {
            Posts = postsModel.ToList(),
            CountPages = posts.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            CountItems = posts.CountItems.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            CurrentId = thread.Key,
            Subdomain = thread.Subdomain,
            CurrentUserName = UserContextService.IsAuthenticated ? UserContextService.Key : String.Empty,
            OwnerThreadName = thread.OwnerUserId,
            OwnerThreadFullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", thread.FirstName, thread.LastName),
            CanAddPost = _threadManager.IsCurrentUserCanUploadContent(thread)
        };
        model.CurrentUserCanDelete = CheckIfUserCanDeletePost(thread);
        return model;
    }
```

JSON Data:

```
    "Posts":[
    {"Key":"Post_ab780bb71",
    "Header":null,
    "Message":"Post details go here ",
    "PostId":"Post_11338",
    "Created":"today",
    "Modified":"today",
    "User":{ User Details below }
```

Comment: It sounds like you're sorting based on the text displayed to the user rather than by the actual date.  You probably need to have two properties on your posts - one with the actual date that you can sort by, the other that you display to the user.

Comment: @JamesThorpe please check the updated question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, however you'll need to make some changes...

You need to use a sortable time format... For example, `2015-10-02T10:09:56`.

I assume the posts have a property called `CreatedOn` which indicate whether it was posted today yesterday etc... Add another property called `CreatedOnSortable` that includes the actual `DateTime` in the format show, you can do this by calling `ToString('s')` on the DateTime...

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s");
```

---

## Edit

### `HomeController`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var livePostModel = new PostsViewModel
    {
        Posts = new Post[]
        {
            new Post
            {
                Created = "Today",
                CreatedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Header = "Todays Post",
                Key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Message = "Todays message",
                Modified = string.Empty,
                PostId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            },
            new Post
            {
                Created = "Yesterday",
                CreatedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1)),
                Header = "Yesterdays Post",
                Key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Message = "Yesterdays message",
                Modified = string.Empty,
                PostId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            },
            new Post
            {
                Created = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(2)).ToString("D"),
                CreatedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(2)),
                Header = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(2)).ToString("D") + " Post",
                Key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Message = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(2)).ToString("D") + " message",
                Modified = string.Empty,
                PostId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            },
            new Post
            {
                Created = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(3)).ToString("D"),
                CreatedDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(3)),
                Header = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(3)).ToString("D") + " Post",
                Key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Message = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(3)).ToString("D") + " message",
                Modified = string.Empty,
                PostId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            },
        }
    };

    this.ViewBag.Json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(livePostModel);

    return View();
}
```

### `Index.cshtml`

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: posts">
    <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="text: Created"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6" data-bind="text: CreatedSortable"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><button data-bind="click: orderByAsc">Order Ascending</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><button data-bind="click: orderByDesc">Order Descending</button></div>
</div>


@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var json = @this.Html.Raw(this.ViewBag.Json);

        function Post(post) {
            var self = this;
            self.key = ko.observable(post.Key || '');
            self.header = ko.observable(post.Header || '');
            self.message = ko.observable(post.Message || '');
            self.postId = ko.observable(post.PostId || '');
            self.created = ko.observable(post.Created || '');
            self.createdSortable = ko.observable(post.CreatedSortable || '');
            self.modified = ko.observable(post.Modified || '');
        }

        function PostsViewModel(model) 
        {
            var self = this;
            self.posts = ko.observableArray(model.Posts);

            self.orderByAsc = function() {
                self.posts.sort(function(left, right) { return left.CreatedSortable == right.CreatedSortable ? 0 : (left.CreatedSortable < right.CreatedSortable ? 1:-1 ) });
            }

            self.orderByDesc = function() {
                self.posts.sort(function(left, right) { return left.CreatedSortable == right.CreatedSortable ? 0 : (left.CreatedSortable < right.CreatedSortable ? -1: 1 ) });
            }
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new PostsViewModel(json));
    </script>

}
```

### `Result`

Ascending
[image]

Descending
[image]

Comment: The property is `this.Created = ko.observable(ThreadId);` I am not sure how would I implement your solution to it as I am not a frontend dev.

Comment: Can you add the properties of `PostModel` as well please, or even betterm you can add the JSON that you're sending to the view, from that I can construct an example of how to use the data

Comment: Added JSON that is sent to view. @AydinAdn

Comment: Sweet, I'll be back with an example in a moment

Comment: pay attention to the new properties on `Post`

Comment: The Post property in the model is already in DateTime type. The website uses moment.js to change the dates. You're solution works, however I am not sure if I should change the existing code to that. Can you provide any solution to sort date via KO bind or momentJS ?

Comment: I just have :) That value must always be there in that format for you to be able to sort the data, when using moment.js, copy the modified values to another variable, don't overwrite the raw data

Comment: I understand what you mean, but the I can't find where it is changing the raw date to momentjs day. neither on client side nor on ASP. The application was built previously by another developer. I'll select your answer as correct as it provides the answer. Thank you